# Is the sentence "despite a new version having been released (...) " correct?

Tags: present-perfect

Is the present perfect tense used correctly in the following sentence?

*Despite a new version 2.0.0 having been released in 2015, the version 1.0.0 remains most widely used.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Igid's comment, which I would call an answer. Here are some examples which may clarify things a bit:

> Despite a new version 2.0.0 having been released in 2015, version 1.0.0 remains the most widely used.
>   Despite a new version 2.0.0 having been released in 2015, version 1.0.0 remains very widely used.
>   Despite a new version 2.0.0 having been released in 2015, the first version remains the most widely used.

So, as Igid says, you wouldn't put *the* in front of *version 1.0.0*. This is because it functions as a proper noun; it's part of the name of a software title. You *would* put *the* in front of *most widely used* because you are actually saying *the most widely used version,* and the superlative is constructed with *the*.

However, it is possible that you are using *most* in the secondary sense of *very*, with a little stronger emphasis: *This discussion is most interesting.* This is rather uncommon (BrE uses it a bit more often than AmE), but if it is your meaning, you wouldn't use *the* in front of it. In the case of this sentence, using *most* would sound like you had forgotten to put *the* in the sentence, unless someone gave it a bit of thought. I prefer *very* here, or perhaps some word like *extremely* if *very* didn't convey my feelings strongly enough.

The third example does use *the*, because *version* isn't a proper noun.